# How to use pipeline script to transfer zip files from the workspace to slave machine (target server) that I have set up already

Tags: ssh, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I want to use use pipeline script to transfer zip files from the workspace to slave machine (target server) that I have set up and I need the snippet to do the same in the stage 'Deploy'

I know how to achieve this using the below command

sh ‘scp -r dist user@server:/var/www/temp_deploy/dist/’

but is doesnt seem like its using the slave setup as it is just using the ssh on the go. is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, for `scp`/`ssh` to work, the host must be known to the originating machine, and the passwordless `ssh` needs to be set up.

To make a host known, first connect from the originating machine to the target manually (make sure the user is the same as the one running the job). Alternatively, use `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@server`.

To set up passwordless ssh, you need to generate a keypair and then copy the public key to the receiving machine.

Finally, you can use `stash`/`unstash` groovy functions:

When your zip is ready, use

```
stash name: 'dist', includes: 'path/to/the/zip', allowEmpty: true
```

On the other machine, use

```
unstash 'dist'
```

Behind the scenes, this will pack your files and move it over to the other machine, where these will be unpacked into the same place in the workspace.